# Android canvas reusing bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have a lot of geometries that need to be draw on a canvas (Overlay in osmdroid but i don't think is important.
Because i have so many objects it is not possible to create on bitmap for each object(geometry).

draw method looks like this:

```
protected void draw(Canvas c, MapView osmv, boolean shadow) {
        Bitmap airSpaceBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight() , Config.ARGB_8888);
        Path path = new Path();
        for (Airspace airspace : restrictedAirspaces) {
            airSpaceBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);//clean current bitmap
            Canvas airSpaceCanvas=new Canvas(airSpaceBitmap);
            path.reset();
            //build the path
            airSpaceCanvas.drawPath(path, AIRSPACE_RESTRICTED);
            //draw other stuff in the bitmap
            //clip only the needed part from the draw
            airSpaceCanvas.clipPath(clipPath, Region.Op.REPLACE);
            c.drawBitmap(airSpaceBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        }

    }
```

The problem is that only last draw (last bitmap) is draw not all.
Any idea on why and how to fix this?

Comment: read about 2nd and 3rd parameter of `Canvas#drawBitmap(Bitmap, int, int, Paint)`

Comment: The problem does not seem to be position of my bitmap. The idea is that i'm creating a bitmap with the same size of the canvas. I draw all i need in that bitmap and draw that bitmap on canvas, then (by reusing this bitmap) i clean the bitmap and draw again on canvas. I don't know why my last bitmap disapears from the canvas.

Comment: you are drawing airSpaceBitmaps at positiom 0, 0 again and again so only the last is seen, BTW what is `Canvas airSpaceCanvas` used for?

Comment: Yes that is waht i'm doing but i was hopping (since my bitmap is transparent) to have the bitmaps draw one over on other. airSpaceCanvas is the canvas used to draw in the airSpaceBitmap.